# Dynamically attaching 'onerror' event to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a page that displays a list of images. However, one or two of these images will error out depending on what the user searches for. Ideally, I would like to attach an onerror event to these images so I can display another image instead of the bad image.

However, these images are displayed using a sharepoint/lync library and I have no control over their declaration. When they get declared, I am simply passing the function a picture URL and that's it. I cannot specify an onerror event.

Is there a way to dynamically attach this event to any image that gets created on the page?

I was thinking something along the lines of this

```
        $("img").on('onerror', function ()
        {
            alert("test");
        });
```

However, this attempt is unsuccessful. I know jquery has an error() method, but this does not work since images are created at runtime

```
        $("img").error(function ()
        {
            alert("test");
        });
```

Comment: have you tried .on("error", function() {}) ?

Comment: yes. Didn't seem to work as well

Comment: That's equivalent to his last code. The issue is that the images are added dynamically, so he needs to use event delegation. But I'm not sure that works with images, because they don't bubble. http://m.cg/post/30934181934/error-events-dont-bubble-from-images-and-how-to-work

Answer (score 1):

As images are created at runtime, [use **event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#using-the-triggering-element):

```
$(document).on("error", "img", (function (){
     alert("test");
});
```

Comment: looks promising. though I'm having trouble getting the intended result. Please see the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/3JHzq/

Comment: You can use this - http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/3JHzq/1/ - it works simply by setting the `onerror` attribute to `alert("test");`, you can even call functions or do whatever you want, like removing the image altogether - http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/3JHzq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the images and loading. If they don't exist, replace.

```
$.each($('img'), function(){
    var test = new Image();
    $(test).load(function () {
        //if error, load alternate
    });
    test.src = $(this).src;
});
```